# Scrapy call request in a loop

Tags: python, request, web-crawler, scrapy

I want to scrap a web page which contains comobobox with filtering options.
The base url is the same but the request payload depends on selected combobox value. I have a list of available options and I've created a loop which iterate over the combobox values and execute request. Code below:

```
def parse_product_lines(self, response):
    options = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
    product_lines = options['products']

    for product_line in product_lines:
        payload = self.prepare_payload(product_line)

        scrapy.Request('http://example.com',
                       method="POST",
                       body=urllib.urlencode(payload),
                       callback=self.parse_items)

def parse_items(self, response):
    print response
```

,but requests are not executed. Do somebody know what's going on there ?

Comment: When at the end of the loop I added return statement everything started to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first, a `Spider` class use method `parse` by default.

each callback should return an `Item` or a `dict`, or an iterator.

you should `yield request` in your `parse_product_lines` method to tell scrapy to handle next.

Answer (score 3):

Scrapy doesn't wait for a `Request` to finish (like other requests libraries), it calls requests asychronously.

These requests (and items) are being handled by every method that handles those requests (callbacks) by yielding them, because scrapy takes those methods as `generators` and checks if they are items or requests, returning the items, and scheduling the request to be handled later by the method specified on its `callback` parameter.

So don't just call `Request`, but `yield Request` to be scheduled by scrapy.